# how to Isolated $row element

Tags: php

how to echo all item in row (mysql) and Isolated ","

```
//  samle : $row_Recordset1['tags'] is
"tag1,tag2,tag3"
```

i want write For example :

```
<a>tag1</a>

<a>tag2</a> 

<a>tag3</a>
```

Comment: It's still very hard to tell where your data comes from, but you are probably looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tags = split(",",$row_Recordset1['tags']);
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo "<a>" . $tag . "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit vague. But this is what you might be looking for

```
<?php
foreach(split(",", $row_Recordset1['tags']) as $value) {
  echo "<a>".$value."</a>";
}
?>
```